# mysql varchar sort

Tags: mysql, sql

I have VARCHAR row with values like: "1, 11, 2, 6, 2A, 10, 6B"
How to select them ordered like: 1, 2, 2A, 6, 6B, 10, 11 ?

Tried simple SQL query but this did not work.

```
SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY id
```

Comment: How did it not work?  Because for the sample data you posted, I would expect it should.  (Assuming, of course, that `id` is the name of the row you want to sort by.)

Comment: @bdares: nope, it would do `1, 10, 11, 2, 2A, 6, 6B`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CONVERT`.

This will sort first by the number and then by the letter (otherwise you'll not be guaranteed to have 1, 1A, 1B etc)

```
SELECT id FROM clients ORDER BY CONVERT(id, UNSIGNED), id
```

Comment: Also this works in mysql: `SELECT id FROM clients ORDER BY id*1, id`

Answer (score 2):

To borrow from previous answers, casting or converting the column to a numeric expression in the `ORDER` clause is a common solution for ordering values in a character field numerically.

**Partial Solution**

```
SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY CAST(`id` AS DECIMAL)
```

However, this solution is most often implemented against strictly numeric values. Since your values are a mixture of a number followed by a letter, this solution isn't enough. If you have values where the leading decimal portion are identical, such as `2`, `2A`, and `2B`, they could appear in any order.

**Complete Solution**

So, once the values are ordered numerically, it should be further ordered with the standard (lexicographic) ordering:

```
SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY CAST(`id` AS DECIMAL), id
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [`CAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

```
CAST(expr AS type)
```

Your SQL Query should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY CAST(`id` AS DECIMAL), id
```

Comment: I'm sure MySQL can sort lexically, which is what he seems to want.

Comment: @bdares he wants decimal sorting too, if it would be just lexically, `1` would be followed by `11` and not by `2`

Comment: @bdares, if that's the case, he would probably mention it, but as long as he is ok with my solution, there's no need for anything else.

Comment: With this solution, how would '2A, 2B, and 2C' be ordered?

Comment: they wouldn't. for that case there is an OTHER different solution. end.

Comment: @develroot: it is very simple to add the letter order, see my answer.

Comment: @nico okay i forgot about that